# Father Son Relation

Tags: sql-server

I want to design a database which stores the family members and a query can be constructed to find that who is father of whom. In short a father son relationship.

This is what I came up with

**Family**

```
|   id     |      Name    |
---------------------------
|   1      |   Ankit      |
---------------------------
|   2      |   Nishant    |

......
```

and in relation to this to find the relation of son and father
I created another table

**Father**

```
|  father_id    |    Son_id    |
--------------------------------
|   1           |       2      |
-------------------------------
.....
```

I feel its not correct can someone guide me and what query needs to be written to get such a relation.

Thanks in advance

EDIT

ok I tried to the query now but somehow i am getting the error 
This is what I am doing

```
select f.name as father_name, s.name as son_name
from (select family.name from family,father where father.father_id = family.id ) as f Inner Join
(select family.name from family,father where father.son_id = family.id) as s 
on
(family.id = father.father_id and family.id = father.son_id)
```

the error is

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "family.id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "father.father_id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "family.id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "father.son_id" could not be bound.
```

Comment: Why do you feel this is not correct? A relation of a table on itself is perfectly OK.

Comment: I had an idea that it will work but didn't knew that it is th correct method to do so as one might enter hus own id..  A person can not be his own father..  So i was in doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, theres nothing wrong.

You could write a join query to join to itself based on the id's in the relations table

```
SELECT dad.name AS fathers_name, son.name AS sons_name
FROM father AS R

INNER JOIN family AS dad ON dad.id = R.father_id
INNER JOIN family AS son ON son.id = R.son_id
```

EDIT:

This is my sql server version. I have this working without any problems.

Comment: I did it in access so you may not need the parenthesis for sql server. Do a test query first.

Comment: I tried your way but somehow getting error in the query please can you help me. I just edited the question

Answer (score 2):

What you have will work just fine, but you could do it with a single table

```
Id   Name      Father
1    Ankit     Null
2    Nishant   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your design can work.  There's nothing "wrong" with it.

But there's another way.

You could have a FATHER_ID column in the FAMILY table that points to the father row.  It's a foreign key that refers to itself. You don't need a separate table that way.

Comment: Can you please guide me with the query.. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your table design is correct, however I would have renamed the tables `Person` and `RelationShip`

```
SELECT
  FamliyFather.name AS FatherName
  , FamliySon.name AS SonName
FROM
  Family AS FamliyFather
  INNER JOIN Father
    ON FamliyFather.id = Father.father_id
  INNER JOIN Family AS FamliySon
    ON Father.son_id = FamliySon.id
```

If you need the complete tree of your ancestors you should use a CTE.